# How can I refer to specific cell within non contiguous named range?

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I am trying to create a new named range with reference to a specific cell in a non-contiguous named range. Please see the example picture:

[image]

Named_range consists of two ranges, K4:K7 and L8:L10.
I cannot find a way to refer to specific cells, for example cells 4 (K7) and 6 (L9).
I have tried to use index, =index(Named_range,4) but it works only for cell 4. For cell 6 it refers K9 instead of L9.

The desired ending is something like this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Named_range_cell_6", RefersTo:=Index("Named_range", 6)
```

I cannot find a way to create a named range with reference to already existing Named_range, like in the "INDEX(Named_range,6)" attempt. Things like Range("Named range").Item(6) do exactly the same thing, refer to things within one row or column. I want to refer to THAT one specific cell based on its index regardless if it's contiguous or non-contiguous range.

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Note that you can use the 4th parameter of INDEX since your range has more than one area.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I can use 4th parameter, but I cannot use any further parameter. What I am looking for is an option or feature to use 6th parameter or any other in the second/third area of my named range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the range is severely disjoint, you would need a loop:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim i As Long, r As Range

    Union(Range("K4:K7"), Range("L8:L10")).Name = "Named_range"
    i = 1
    For Each r In Range("Named_range")
        If i = 6 Then
            r.Name = "Named_range_6"
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next r

    MsgBox Range("Named_range_6").Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]